# what is difference between site definition and web template?

Tags: sharepoint

Yesterday in one interview they asked what is difference between site definition and web templates? Really I was confused. Can any one tell me the differences? I googled but not got the specific answer.

Answer (score 2):

1. **Site definition** affects an entire site collection created from it.
   **Web template** is site-scoped.
2. **Site definitions** consist of files stored on a front-end web server in folders under the `\(14 hive)\TEMPLATE\SiteTemplates` directory.
   **Web templates** are stored in the database.
3. **Web templates** are based on existing sites, so they depend on the site definition used to create their base site.

More information: [Site Types: WebTemplates and Site Definitions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms434313.aspx)